# How to add custom login logout links in Bootstrap theme?

Tags: 7, navigation

I am new to drupal, but I had a requirement, my current site using bootstrap theme. Previously there was no login and logout buttons on header. Today I got html login and logout strip from desinger. For this I have created a new block and selected bootstrap region as Navigation. Now this custom header perfectly sits at the top of the page. with static Myaccout, Logout , contactus  which are sent by desinger.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Navigator</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>

          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
<li> <a href="#">My Account </a></li>
 <li> <a href="#">Log Out </a></li>
 </ul>    
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

But my question how to make that header dynamic like when user with out login need to show Login , and after login need to show myaccount and logout. Above code is the static html bootstrap header sent by desinger. Please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Hi, you could render or place the user menu block in the navigation regions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done this way

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
<?php
global $user; 
 if($user->uid):?>
<li> <a href="#">My Account </a></li>
<li> <a href="#">Log Out </a></li>
<?php else: ?>
<li> <a href="/user">Log in</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Edit the code between your ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> to make it look like this:

```
<?php if(global $user):?>
<li> <a href="#">My Account </a></li>
<li> <a href="#">Log Out </a></li>
<?php else: ?>
<li> <a href="/user">Log in</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```